# Qty available by location (again)

Tags: odoo-8, odoo, odoo-9

I know this was discussed before but it's not really working for me. How can i get qty available for location or warehouse my product is now.

(Most of the answers are in old API and this one not really working for me)

```
class ProductProduct(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.template'

  available_qty = fields.Integer(
    string='Qty By Loc',
    compute='product_qty_location_check',
)


    def product_qty_location_check(self): 
        if self: 

            self.available_qty = self.with_context({'location' : self.source_location.id}).qty_‌​available 

AttributeError: 'product.template' object has no attribute 'source_location'
```

Comment: There is no field like source_location in product.template class.You should add your custom field in product.template class.

Comment: is it' has to be many2one('stock.location') ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to find out your location and/or warehouse. There are enough possibilities to do so:

1. use a wizard which has a field
2. search by reference e.g. `self.env.ref('my_module.my_location')`
3. use other sources

Now you can use them on `product.product`'s `_product_available()`. Just call that method on one or more products (recordssets) and evaluate the result of this method. To filter for locations and/or warehouses use the context. For example:

```py
# get a recordset of all products
products = self.env['product.product'].search([])
# get a special location (my_location)
location = self.env.ref('my_module.my_location')
quantities = products.with_context(location=location.id)._product_available()
# print the quantities
for product_id, quantity_dict in quantities.iteritems():
    print product_id
    print quantity_dict
```

The same is possible with `with_context(warehouse=warehouse.id)` or even with list of IDs or names: `with_context(location=[1,2,3])`, `with_context(location="My Location")`

Answer (score 1):

To get the quantity by location you need to search the *location* with the *product_id* in *stock.quant*

Use the below sample in your compute function:

```
quant_sr = self.env["stock.quant"].search([('location_id','=',self.source_location.id),('product_id','=',self.product_id.id)])
qty = 0.0
for quant in quant_sr:
    qty += quant.qty
print qty
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'product.template' object has no attribute 'source_location' , probably i need to do it in other model or? can't find this field in any model. any solution?

Comment: Already there is smart button which shows the OnHand Quantity in product.template. Then why do you need another field?